# Compare answer from user and possible answer in array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My input text field has two possible answers which are "luah" or "hal" but my code is not working :

```
stop();

//var jawapan1=Array;

txt_zuhal.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,handler);

function handler(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
    //jawapan1=("luah", "hal");

    // if the key is ENTER
    if(event.charCode == 13)
    {      
        if(txt_zuhal.text == 'luah'||'hal')
        {       
            trace("1.correct");
        }
        else
        {   
            trace("1.Sorry, Wrong answer");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your if statement is not correct syntax, try this: `if (txt_zuhal.text =='luah' || txt_zuhal.text == 'hal')`

Answer (score 0):

```
    private function handler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {

        //jawapan1=("luah", "hal");

        // if the key is ENTER

        if(event.charCode == 13)
        {
            if(txt_zuhal.text == "luah" || txt_zuhal.text == "hal")
            {       
                trace("1.correct");
            }
            else
            {   
                trace("1.Sorry, Wrong answer");
            }
        }
    }
```